# Resonance energy

Tags: organic-chemistry

Which resonating structures are more stable . How to comment about stability among resonating structures . What are its criterea ?  Explain with simple examples with rule?

Comment: You should provide more information, for example by adding  the structures you are trying to compare and your attempt at reasoning the answer out.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: I have already mention tag of homework question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rule for comparing resonance structures, but it is always useful to follow the following steps:

1. the structure with more covalent bonds is more stable
2. the structure in which all atoms have an octet is more stable
3. the structure with less unlike charge separation is more stable
4. the structure with charges on carbon atoms are unstable
5. structures with positive charge on electronegative atoms are unstable.

Comment: Ty Daenys for u answer

Comment: Please help me to how to post pic on this site